# My count(s.section_id) is returning to many rows

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to do a query that will return a list of locations, the number of sections taught in the location, and the number of total students in that location. My column calculating the count of students works fine but my count to return how many sections return way to many even when I just list the section id as well with it, it only returns the actual amount but for some reason, my count doesn't. It has to be something with how I'm using both the section and enrollment table because when I remove my enrollment table it works great but I can't get the count of students.

```
SELECT s.location,count(s.section_id), count(e.student_id)
FROM section s, enrollment e
WHERE s.section_id = e.section_id 
GROUP BY s.location
ORDER BY s.location
```

returns:

```
H310    1   1
L206    8   8
L210    29  29
L211    10  10
L214    36  36
L500    14  14
L507    36  36
L509    72  72
L511    3   3
M200    1   1
M311    11  11
M500    5   5
```

It should however return

```
H310    1   1
L206    1   8
L210    10  29
L211    3   10
L214    15  36
L500    2   14
L507    15  36
L509    25  72
L511    1   3
M200    1   1
M311    3   11
M500    1   5
```

Comment: Without knowing your data, it may be hard to find why you aren't getting what you desire. Try using `count(distinct s.section_id)` instead of `count(s.section_id)` - it's a wild guess.

Comment: please add the table definition  and sample data may be for location `L206`

Comment: That because of one-many relation between section and student table. Now you can use `COUNT(DISTINCT section_id)` and give it a try.

Comment: it helps if you sample your input data as well , but I'm guessing `count(distinct s.section_id)` can be the answer?

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using. Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

you may want to add `DISTINCT` to your count for section column because It multiplies it when you join it with enrollment table:

```
SELECT s.location,count(DISTINCT s.section_id), count(e.student_id)
FROM section s, enrollment e
WHERE s.section_id = e.section_id 
GROUP BY s.location
ORDER BY s.location
```

Comment: So i thought that as well but for some reason, it then returns less than it should on some rows.

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause,  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  It has been part of the standard -- literally -- for decades.

The solution is to use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.  It is only needed for the sections:

```
SELECT s.location, COUNT(DISTINCT s.section_id) as num_sections, 
       COUNT(e.student_id) as num_students
FROM section s JOIN
     enrollment e
     ON s.section_id = e.section_id 
GROUP BY s.location
ORDER BY s.location;
```

`COUNT()` counts the number of non-`NULL` values for the column.

Note that this query counts only sections that have students.  If you want all of them (if some could not have any enrollment), then use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`.